# System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."

Tags: c#

Собственно говоря заголовок говорит сам за себя, не могу понять что не так. 
Буду благодарен за помощь

```
public int UserChoose()
    {
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (temp)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали камень");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали ножницы");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали бумагу");
                break;

        }
        return temp;

    }
```

Comment: И чего вы пишете в консоли? Напишите `string value = Console.ReadLine(); Debugger.Break();  int temp = Convert.ToInt32(value);`, запустите, введите значение и наведите на `value` в коде, что там?

Answer (score 3):

```
public int UserChoose()
{
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int temp))
    {
        switch (temp)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали камень");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали ножницы");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали бумагу");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Неверный выбор!");
                return 0;
        }
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Введите цифру от 1 до 3.");
    }
    return 0;
 }
```